# What are the cases when get-mailboxstatistics cmdlet returns duplicate mailbox information?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, exchange-2007, exchange-2013

I'm using Exchange 2010 and sometimes I've noticed that the cmdlet get-mailboxstatistics returns duplicate mailbox information. For example, if I move a mailbox from one database to other, the cmdlet shows that particular mailbox information for both databases. What are other cases are there when get-mailboxstatistics cmdlet will be behaving similarly ie. returning duplicate information.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the command you are running in your question and specific like if you are using archiving.

Comment: I'm just using this command - Get-MailboxStatistics
No, I'm not using any archiving. One instance I noticed this was when I move a mailbox from one database to other. In that case, get-mailboxstatistics told me that the mailbox is existing in both databases but its size was 0 bytes in the source database(the database from which it was moved).